# Best way for robust hand tracking on PI 4

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection, yolo

I need a robust hand tracking which should be running on a Raspberry Pi 4 model.
Does anyone have some experience with that?

- One way could be to use OpenCV but I think it's just using the skin color for tracking and therefore would not be that robust.
- Another idea is to train TinyYolo for that and using NNPACK to do parallel computation on multicore CPU.
  (is there a pretrained hand-detection yolo model?)

Thanks for any advice,
Cheers